# Asymptotic expression of $f(x) = \sum \dfrac{1}{n} \tanh(\frac{x}{n})$ as $x\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, asymptotics

Find an asymptotic expression of $f(x) = \sum \dfrac{1}{n} \tanh(\frac{x}{n})$ as $x\to \infty$.

What I did: I considered that, for all $n\geq 1$, since $t \mapsto \dfrac{1}{t} \tanh(\frac{x}{t})$ is decreasing for $x\geq0$:

$$\int_{n}^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{t} \tanh(\frac{x}{t})dt\leq\dfrac{1}{n} \tanh(\frac{x}{n})\leq \int_{n-1}^n \dfrac{1}{t} \tanh(\frac{x}{t})dt$$
By substitution ($u = \dfrac{x}{t}$):
$$\int_{x/(n+1)}^{x/n} \dfrac{\tanh(u)}{u} du\leq\dfrac{1}{n} \tanh(\frac{x}{n})\leq \int_{x/n}^{x/(n-1)} \dfrac{\tanh(u)}{u} du$$
But then, I don't know what to do. I've tried some integration by parts, but was not able to find anything that converges when I finally sum.

Comment: What is "th"?${}$

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I forgot that it's $tanh$ in English... Just corrected it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing over $n$ your last inequality shows that $f(x)$ goes like
$$
\int_0^x \frac{\tanh(u)}{u} \,du \simeq \log(x)
$$
since $\frac{\tanh(u)}{u}\simeq\frac1u$.

Moreover, you could prove that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} [f(x) - \log(x)]
$$
exists.

Comment: Oh yeah I see now! Thank you very much. (Btw, it should be $log(x)$ not $log(u)$ in front of you integral.

Comment: @MiKiDe sure, fixed!